# Import can not resolve error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web

In my Spring web application i am trying to import below given imports to annotate my class as `@Configuration` and method as `@Bean`

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
```

But i am reciving compile time error that the imports does not resolve.

Do i need to add any perticular jar for these imports?

Comment: have you included Spring libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **spring-context** in your classpath.

You can find the library [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context) or [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Jar Finder`](http://www.jarfinder.com), search by `class name`

```
 org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
 org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
```

and then add the necessary jars to your build path.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Spring jars are present and that they are included as libraries in your project.